# SharePoint 2013 Workflow, InfoPath Email Body is blank empty truncated

Tags: workflow, infopath, email, office, windows

This started occurring after SP1 was applied to SharePoint 2013 and or IE11 was introduced to the Windows Environment on Windows 7 and Windows 10 devices.

If we send email using PowerShell as a test the same issue occurs. Html or Plain Text email body. As far as I am aware this is the same library SPD workflows and InfoPath use to send email see below. Not the full script below for brevity.

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail($web,0,0,$email,$subject,$body);
```

If I send using a `PowerShell Script` using the `Net.Mail.SmtpClient` typically used in `C# .NET` to send emails Plain text or Html it works, same email body.

Answer (score 0):

This Turned out to be an Issue with Outlook 2013 / IE 11, applying all the latest Windows Updates for Office 2013 and IE 11 resolved the problem. This effected Windows 7 Operating Systems and Windows 10 Operating systems.

So the Message was sent however Outlook could not render it. This occurred over a 3 week period eventually I red a post indicating rolling IE 11 back could resolve this issue caused by IE 11, Office Outlook 2013 relies on Windows 11 for some functions. Rather than roll IE 11 out I decided to install all the latest Windows Office and IE 11 updates in the hope this would resolve the issue which it did.